# How to pass an array to a function without mutating the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, mutation

I'm working on a helper function within a bigger function.

I have an array of team object (each team looks like this {team:`unique number of the team`, points:0, goalDiff:0, goalsFor:0}) as the first argument of my function and I have an array of game results as a second argument (each game looks like this [number ref home team, number ref away team, goals scored by home team, goals scored by away team]).

My function looks at each game in the second array and allocate 2 points to the winning team and zero to the losing one. in case of draw, it allocates 1 point to each team. Function also counts the goals scored by each team.

```
    let computeGames = (arr, games) => {

  
    games.forEach((game) => {
      
      let homeTeamIndex = arr.findIndex(team => team.team === game[0])
      let awayTeamIndex = arr.findIndex(team => team.team === game[1])
      let homeTeam = arr[homeTeamIndex]
      let awayTeam = arr[awayTeamIndex]
    
      
      game[2] > game[3]
        ? (homeTeam.points += 2)
        : game[2] === game[3]
        ? ((homeTeam.points += 1), (awayTeam.points += 1))
        : (awayTeam.points += 2);
      homeTeam.goalsFor += game[2];
      awayTeam.goalsFor += game[3];
      homeTeam.goalDiff += game[2] - game[3];
      awayTeam.goalDiff += game[3] - game[2];
    });

  return arr
    
  };
```

My code is counting the points and goals as expected, but my issue is that when I execute something like the code below, the points are being counted in my teams array as well as in my doNotMutate array.
I do not understand why teams is being mutated given it's a copy of teams that is passed to the function, not the teams array itself. If someone could explain, I'm getting really confused here.

Cheers

```
const teams = createTeams(number) // this is a helper function to generate my teams with all values = 0
let doNotMutate = [...teams]

doNotMutate= computeGames(doNotMutate,games)
  
  console.log(teams, doNotMutate)
```

Comment: Please give input and expected output

Comment: Doing `[...teams]` does not copy the objects stored within the array. You'll want to step through the array and map each item to `{...obj}` (i.e. `[...teams].map(g=>({...g}))`) or explore deep-clone implementations.

Comment: Objects are always "passed by reference", so although you're using the spread operator to perform a shallow copy, modifications done to the object properties will be reflected in both the original and the copied list.

Comment: Thanks James, I'll try that. So at the moment what's in my array is still a reference to the original object ? no matter in which array they are located ?

Comment: Yes. You can either deep-clone the objects or write your function so it doesn't mutate the list. I would recommend the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `[...teams]` does not copy the objects stored within the array. Each item of the array is simply copied into a new array. In your case each item is an object, meaning the new array will contain the exact same objects (think of them as *"references to the same value"* if that helps).

You can observe this:

```
teams[0] === doNotMutate[0] // true! (we don't want this)
```

You'll want to step through the array and map each item to a copy of itself (`{...obj}`). Something like this:

```
const doNotMutate = [...teams].map(game => ({...game}));
```

Alternatively, explore deep-clone implementations such as [lodash's](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep).